# How can I change the attributes of a SVG line?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

There are two lines "LongLine" and "ShortLine".

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<line id="LongLine" x1="20" y1="350" x2="350" y2="50" stroke-width="2" stroke="black"/>
<line id="ShortLine" x1="20" y1="350" x2="0" y2="0" stroke="#ff00ff" stroke-width="10" />
</svg>
```

I want to change the attributes of "ShortLine". The "ShortLine" must have the same angle, but it is short than "LongLine". The attributes of "ShortLine" could be e.g. as follows (x1="20" y1="350" x2="185" y2="200").

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<line id="LongLine" x1="20" y1="350" x2="350" y2="50" stroke-width="2" stroke="black"/>
<line id="ShortLine" x1="20" y1="350" x2="185" y2="200" stroke="#ff00ff" stroke-width="10" />
</svg>
```

In other words x1, y1, x2, y2 of "LongLine", and x1, y1 of "ShortLine" are known. 

Wanted are the x2, y2 of "ShortLine", but so that the angle of both lines remains the same.

Here is my wrong approach:https://jsfiddle.net/rmLdm15z/8/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want the slope of short line to be same as that of long line ?

Comment: Yes, the angle and slope of both lines should remain the same.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
var shortLine = document.getElementById('ShortLine')
shortLine.y1.baseVal.value = 500

console.log(shortLine)
// Gives us:
// <line id="ShortLine" x1="20" y1="500" x2="185" y2="200" stroke="#ff00ff" stroke-width="10"></line>
```

As a general guideline, you can always view all the properties an object gives you through the console. For example, `console.log(shortLine.y1)` is how you find that you can set `baseVal.value`.

Comment: I do not know what you mean? It does not work for me. See here: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/rmLdm15z/9/)

Comment: Your question was how to change svg attributes - hence my answer demonstrating how to do exactly that.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. The title of my question is that, but my question contains explanation. Anyway, I am grateful to you for your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to calculate the unit vector `u` given by the points `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` of the "LongLine", then add it to `(x1, y1)` multiplied by the desired size of the "ShortLine", call it `short_d`.

```
const dx = x2 - x1
const dy = y2 - y1
const d = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
const ux = dx / d
const uy = dy / d

const shortLine = document.getElementById('ShortLine')
shortLine.setAttribute('x1', `${x1}`)
shortLine.setAttribute('y1', `${y1}`)
shortLine.setAttribute('x2', `${x1 + short_d * ux}`)
shortLine.setAttribute('y2', `${y1 + short_d * uy}`)
```

Take a look on [Vector algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_algebra).